# There is some windows config that optimizes HDD reads?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, performance

Once I found on internet that if you enable the options over Windows Seven Control Panel/System/Device Manager/Disc units/"Your HDD Model"/Policies and enable or disable one or both options (I dont rebember) you would get a huge performance improvement for disk reads. Anyone knows if this is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would get a boost from *enabling* the first option (write cache) but this is not a good idea if you live in an area prone to power outages.

Comment: I might add that the second option will, in some cases, also give a moderate boost to performance but it as well can result in a trashed HDD if the power gets interrupted while it's transferring the cache.